# Ошибка в построении серии LineSeries в библиотеке OxyPlot

Tags: c#, визуализация, oxyplot

График строится нормально, но при масштабировании линии отображаются как то не понятно[image: Масштабированное изображение]

Вот так выглядит не масштабированный график:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Серию заполняю из базы данных с помощью DataReader. Значения в базу пишутся каждые 5 секунд.

```
if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                        ser.Points.Add(new DataPoint(TimeSpanAxis.ToDouble(dr.GetDateTime(0)), dr.GetDouble(1)));
                        scatterSeries.Points.Add(new ScatterPoint(TimeSpanAxis.ToDouble(dr.GetDateTime(0)), dr.GetDouble(1), 4, 38.4));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Вопрос собственно в чем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблемы была в самой выборке из БД, к запросу добавил order by timestamp и все нормально заработало !